# How is data stored on a CardDav server?

Tags: webdav, carddav

I wanted to ask a question about server data. I am new to server programming, but I have to learn about the CardDav server (CardDav is developed by the WebDav).

I only know the CardDav server is used to hold the address book data, but what form of the data does the server actually hold (e.g. .CSV or .txt)? Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file format used is **vCard**; the wikipedia entry contains a basic explanation of the file format:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard

For the gory details, take a look at RFC2426: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2426

Comment: would you mind I ask one more question about the server. What is the file type stored of the CalDav server. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSiu: this depends on the CalDAV server, there are several implementations. Atmail (http://atmail.com/), for example, uses a MySQL database, and I assume that other products also use a similar approach.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I found some information in the wiki and I found that one of the format is the iCalendar. Is it right?

Answer (score 8):

The format **on the server** is up to the server. The format on the wire is vCard (RFC 2426, to be updated soonish).

Comment: thank you for your reply. As I am the green of the server programming, would you mind to explain what is 'format on the wire'? Thank you.

Comment: "Format on the wire" refers to what is sent in HTTP messages, as opposed to what happens inside the server.

Comment: This answer is the better one.